# How to remove previously loaded Ajax field?

Tags: ajax

I have an dropdown that uses `Ajax` to display a field if a specific option is selected.

HTML:

```
<select name="test" id="testID" onChange="myFunc()">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<div id="display"></div>
```

AJAX SCRIPT:

```
<script>
function myFunc() {
if(document.getElementById('testID').value == "3") {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML =
this.responseText;
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "_ajax_test1.cfm", true);
xhttp.send();
}

else if(document.getElementById('testID').value == "2"){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML =
this.responseText;
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "_ajax_test2.cfm", true);
xhttp.send();
}

}
</script>
```

If `option 2` or `option 3` is selected, it does work perfectly, but when I click on `option 1` **after** clicking on `option 2` or `option 3`, the last loaded ajax option still remains.

Eg;
If I were to click on `option 2`and then click on `option 1`, option 1 will still display what `option 2` is supposed to display.

So how do I make `option 1` display only its content and not `option 2` or `option 3` contents? (Take note that `option 1` has no `ajax` loaded content)

Comment: How are `myFunc` and `loadPayment` related?  Inside of `loadPayment` you have code for options 2 and 3, but nothing for option 1.  What have you actually tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify your code, you have the following structure:

```
if(document.getElementById('testID').value == "3") {
    // do something
} else if(document.getElementById('testID').value == "2") {
    // do something else
}
```

So what happens when the value equals 1?  *Nothing at all.*  In order for something to happen, you have to write code to make it happen:

```
if(document.getElementById('testID').value == "3") {
    // do something
} else if(document.getElementById('testID').value == "2") {
    // do something else
} else if(document.getElementById('testID').value == "1") {
    // do something here too
}
```

And what is it that you want to happen?  It sounds like you want to set the "display" element to be empty?  So whereas you currently set that element to *something*:

```
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = this.responseText;
```

Instead, set it to *nothing*:

```
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "";
```